# Dplyr possibly is not catching an error - why?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to use possibly together with tidyjson::spread_all.  am confused why possibly is not catching an error thrown by the spread_all function.  Can anyone help me understand how possibly or similar dplyr "adverbs" handle exceptions?

I ran this:

```
profile_res<-
log_data_to_parse %>% 
  filter(!is.na(profile_json)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  extract2('profile_json') %>%
  possibly(tidyjson::spread_all(.),otherwise=tibble(json_err=1111111))
```

I was expecting to get rows with only the column json_error populated and all others NA.  Instead I get:

```
Error in `purrr::map()`:
ℹ In index: 357.
Caused by error in `file.exists()`:
! file name conversion problem -- name too long?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Running rlang::last_trace() gives:

```
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/purrr_error_indexed>
Error in `purrr::map()`:
ℹ In index: 357.
Caused by error in `file.exists()`:
! file name conversion problem -- name too long?
---
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─... %>% ...
  2. ├─purrr::possibly(., tidyjson::spread_all(.), otherwise = tibble(json_err = 1111111))
  3. │ └─purrr:::check_bool(quiet)
  4. │   └─rlang::is_bool(x)
  5. │     └─rlang::is_logical(x, n = 1)
  6. ├─tidyjson::spread_all(.)
  7. │ ├─tidyjson::as.tbl_json(.x)
  8. │ └─tidyjson:::as.tbl_json.character(.x)
  9. │   └─purrr::map(.x, jsonlite::fromJSON, simplifyVector = FALSE)
 10. │     └─purrr:::map_("list", .x, .f, ..., .progress = .progress)
 11. │       ├─purrr:::with_indexed_errors(...)
 12. │       │ └─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 13. │       ├─purrr:::call_with_cleanup(...)
 14. │       └─jsonlite (local) .f(.x[[i]], ...)
 15. │         └─base::file.exists(txt)
 16. └─base::.handleSimpleError(...)
 17.   └─purrr (local) h(simpleError(msg, call))
 18.     └─cli::cli_abort(...)
 19.       └─rlang::abort(...)
```

How can I correctly specify the error handler and return tibble or data frame with a single error value as a column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not using `possibly` correctly. `possibly` takes a function as its first argument (not a function *call*, which is what you are passing). It returns a modified version of the passed function which returns a default value in case of an error.

For example, in your case, you might do:

```r
spread_or_error <- possibly(tidyjson::spread_all, tibble(json_err = 1111111))
```

So you now have a function which, when passed a json string, will return a spread data frame. However, if there is a problem with reading the json, you will get your default data frame.

For example, suppose your column of json strings is:

```r
json_col <- c('{"a" : 1, "b" : 2}', '{"a" : 1, "b" : 2}', 'Not JSON')
```

The first two entries are valid json strings; the third is not. We can `map` this vector to get:

```r
map(json_col, spread_or_error)
#> [[1]]
#> # A tbl_json: 1 x 4 tibble with a "JSON" attribute
#>   ..JSON              document.id     a     b
#>   <chr>                     <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}"           1     1     2
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> # A tbl_json: 1 x 4 tibble with a "JSON" attribute
#>   ..JSON              document.id     a     b
#>   <chr>                     <int> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 "{\"a\":1,\"b\":2}"           1     1     2
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   json_err
#>      <dbl>
#> 1  1111111
```

Comment: Thank you! I ended up not using tidyjson::spread_all, but I am using possibly in the way you illustrated and it works exactly as I wanted.